Google oauth20 identification with passport.js MERN stack project
Hi i am a young developer with less than a year of experience, and I am trying to implement Google OAuth2.0 authentication in my project using Passport.js. I am using the MERN stack and JSON Web Token. I would like to know how I can send my Google user's information to the front end and then retrieve i
The registration part works very well, and I can find my user in MongoDB, but it's the auto-login part that is problematic.
I tried to configure CORS because I couldn't fetch the data via axios. I tried sending the JSON Web Token in the cookie storage and in the URL, and I tried making a fetch request from the backend to google. All of this was in vain. I am desperate.
Here is my backend
import express from "express";
import "dotenv/config";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import multer from "multer";
import productRouter from "./routes/productsRoute";
import userRouter from "./routes/userRoute";
import paymentRouter from "./routes/paymentRoute";
import adminRouter from "./routes/adminRoute";
import { auth, generateToken } from "./middlewares/auth";
import passport from "passport";
import session from "express-session";
import User from "./models/userModel";
import axios from "axios";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";

main().catch((err) => console.log(err));

async function main() {
  await mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/EcomDB");
  console.log(`[DATABASE] MongoDB is connected ⚡️`);
}

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT;
const { Strategy: GoogleStrategy } = require("passport-google-oauth20");
const upload = multer({ dest: "uploads/" });

const corsOptions = {
  origin: ["http://localhost:5173"],
  methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
  allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"],
  credentials: true,
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static("./uploads/images"));
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 },
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:3456/auth/google/callback",
      scope: ["email", "profile"],
    },
    async function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
      try {
        const googleId = profile.id;
        const email = profile.emails[0].value;
        const firstname = profile.name.givenName;
        const lastname = profile.name.familyName;
        const password = "azerty";
        const zipCode = 10000;
        const Adress = "Adresse par défaut";
        const role = "user";
        const userCart = [];
        let googleUser = await User.findOne({ email });

        if (!googleUser) {
          googleUser = await User.create({
            googleId,
            email,
            firstname,
            lastname,
            password,
            zipCode,
            Adress,
            role,
            userCart,
          });
          googleUser.password = await googleUser.encryptedPassword(password);
          googleUser.save();
          const token = generateToken(googleUser.id);
          console.log("user successfully sign");
          return cb(null, { googleUser, token });
        } else {
          const token = generateToken(googleUser.id);
          console.log("user successfully logged in");
          googleUser.token = token;
          return cb(null, googleUser, token);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        return cb(error);
      }
    }
  )
);

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser(async function (user, done) {
  const googleuser = await User.findById(user.id);
  done(null, googleuser);
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json("Welcome");
});

app.get(
  "/auth/google/login",
  passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["email", "profile"] })
);

app.get(
  "/auth/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    failureRedirect: "http://localhost:5173/sign-in",
  }),
  (req, res) => {
    const user = req.user.googleUser || req.user;
    const token = req.user.token || generateToken(user.id);

    res.cookie("jwtToken", token, { httpOnly: true, secure: false });
    res.redirect("http://localhost:5173");
  }
);

app.use("/users", userRouter);
app.use("/products", productRouter);
app.use("/payment", paymentRouter);
app.use("/admin", auth, adminRouter);

app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`[SERVER] Listening on http://localhost:${port}`)
);

Here is my frontend
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";
import { useSnackbar } from "notistack";
import { userInfos } from "../context";

function Login() {
  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const { setUsername, setToken, setUserId, setUserRole } = userInfos();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
    setToken(storedToken);
  }, []);

  const handleGoogleLogin = () => {
    console.log(
      (window.location.href = `http://localhost:3456/auth/google/login`)
    );

    window.location.href = `http://localhost:3456/auth©/google/login`;
  };


  const handleUserLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        `${import.meta.env.VITE_SERVER_URL}/users/connexion`,
        { email, password }
      );
      console.log(response.data);
      const { token } = response.data;
      const decodedUser = jwtDecode(token);
      localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(decodedUser));
      localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(response.data.token));
      setToken(response.data.token);
      setUserId(decodedUser.id);
      setUserRole(decodedUser.role);
      setUsername(decodedUser.name);
      enqueueSnackbar("Connexion successfully completed", {
        variant: "success",
        autoHideDuration: 2000,
      });
      navigate("/");
    } catch (error) {
      enqueueSnackbar("Connexion failed please verify your email or password", {
        variant: "error",
        autoHideDuration: 3000,
      });
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  
  );
}

export default Login;



Have you created a route that will fetch the user's data from DB and send it to the client? Because it seems the login is successful but you don't have any route for user specific data

Why would I need a route that goes from my client to my database? I don't understand.
The Passport.js method with Google OAuth is supposed to authenticate me and then send a response to /auth/google/callback.

Passport.js only authenticates the route and sends the token to the client so they can store it. Other stuff should be done again, for example requesting the user data
